# Theme programmatically added items

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm adding items to a jquery mobile listview problematically. I'm currently using jquery templates to give the new items the jqmobile design.

I would however like to let jQuery mobile style those items. Is it possible? If so, how do I tell jQuery to style the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refresh the jQM controls

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

> **Updating lists**
>  If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create
>   any nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> ```
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
> ```
>
> Note that the `refresh()` method only affects new nodes appended to a
>   list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already
>   enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if
>   you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list
>   item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated,
>   replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

If you need to refresh the whole page look at these docs

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction**
>  Note that there is an important difference between the create event and refresh method
>   that some widgets have. The create event is suited for enhancing raw
>   markup that contains one or more widgets. The refresh method should be
>   used on existing (already enhanced) widgets that have been manipulated
>   programmatically and need the UI be updated to match.
>
> For example, if you had a page where you dynamically appended a new
>   unordered list with data-role=listview attribute after page creation,
>   triggering create on a parent element of that list would transform it
>   into a listview styled widget. If more list items were then
>   programmatically added, calling the listview’s refresh method would
>   update just those new list items to the enhanced state and leave the
>   existing list items untouched.